# Does iPhone support XML-RPC?

Tags: iphone, xml-rpc

Does iPhone support XML-RPC, Is their any open source framework which I can use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Checkout the source for the wordpress app.  They might be using XML-RPC. :)

http://iphone.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 8):

["Airsource Ltd"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147062/does-iphone-support-xml-rpc#147071) is really *really* *incredibly* wrong about that document. That document is specific to Mac OS X and *NOT* the iPhone. In fact (almost) all Apple iPhone documentation is hidden away behind a login page and a licence agreement. Most of the technologies that document refer to (e.g. AppleScript) do not even exist on the iPhone.

Amit, you'll have Zero luck if you follow Airsource's advice. You will however do ok if you do as "[Lounges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147062/does-iphone-support-xml-rpc#147127)" says and go grab the wordpress source code. It looks like they rolled their own XMLRPC library for use on the iPhone.

As for SOAP - you're on your own. You might be able to find an opensource SOAP library built on top of libxml2 though. Good luck.

Comment: yeh I know mate, and I downloaded that code and trying to understand it and even wordpress uses one open source framework.

thanks for your concerns and help.

Comment: Good heavens. You are correct, and I've deleted my incorrect respponse. Perhaps you could delete a few adjectives? I've upvoted your answer anyway...

Answer (score 8):

Yes iPhone support XML-RPC and wordpress opensource application is best example of it,
but from performance aspect I must say JSON is better to use with iPhone application,

from here https://github.com/stig/json-framework/ u can download JSON parser.